# Powershell - Find files that match a pattern for specific number of times

Tags: powershell

To find a simple pattern in a set of files in powershell I go

```
$pattern= 'mypattern'
$r= Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\.." -recurse | 
    Select-String -pattern $pattern | group path | select name
    $r | Out-GridView
```

In my scenario, I have files that contain the pattern for more than one time and others that have the pattern for one time only. So I am interested in those files that contain the pattern for more than one time and not interested in the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for the start of what you are looking for is `Select-String` and `Group-Object` like you already have.

```powershell
Select-String -Path (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\ -Filter *.txt -Recurse) -Pattern "140" -AllMatches | 
    Group-Object Path | 
    Where-Object{$_.Count -gt 1} | 
    Select Name, Count |
    Out-GridView
```

This will take all the txt files in the temp directory and group them by the number of matches. `-AllMatches` is important as by default `Select-String` will only return the first match it finds on a line.

Of those groups we take the ones where the count is higher than one using `Where-Object`. Then we just output the file names and there counts with a `Select Name,Count`. Where `name` is the full file path where the matched text is located.

## About `Out-GridView`

I see that you are assinging the output from `Out-GridView` to `$r`. If you want to do that you need to be sure you add the `-PassThru` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That makes a lot of sense :)